# Why no "variant" any in boost or Standard?

Tags: c++, c++11

One advantage of `any` over `variant` is, that one does not need to specify all types, that it may contain. I've noticed, that as the number of types a `variant` may contain grows, people tend to switch to `any` at some point, because they simply don't keep track of all the types anymore. I think a hybrid between `any` and `variant` is possible. One could store the "`placeholder`" (via placement `new`) of `any` in `aligned_storage`, with the size calculated in a `constexpr` function or template metafunction, from a sample of the largest types, that may end up being stored. The user, on the other hand, would not need to specify all the types, that an `any` might contain. The `any` could also throw at any time, if the user would try to store something larger than the `aligned_storage` in there.

Does such a "`variant_any`" class exist? Is there some inherent problem with the idea?

Comment: Don't know if there is such a type out there. But if needed, maybe add `any` as one of the types to `variant` (note: I've never tried this myself).

Comment: `any` allocates from the heap. `variant` does not have to and `variant_any` would not have to either.

Comment: One catch with the stack based `any` would be copying and moving etc. You would need to figure out a way for the compiler to generate the correct code for any given type. Interesting idea though.

Comment: Interesting. Implementing a proof of concept would further make your point.

Comment: @Niall I did it already for a `variant`, I'm researching if it is feasible to do for an `any`. I think it should be.

Comment: A key property of "variant" is the ability to convert type and preserve value (or call a value-converting function where necessary); boost and the standard don't even start to touch that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That is easy to do with `boost::variant`?  You do need to provide the conversion functions & package them up, but if you have `boost::variant< A, B, C >` using a visitor to turn it into an `A`, then storing it back solves that problem?  `var = apply_visitor( to_A, var )`? (sure, you have to write `to_A`)

Comment: I don't get it. What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The unwieldy long list of template parameters, that you may need to supply to a `variant` class template.

Comment: @user1095108: Right, `any` gives you that. What would your proposed "hybrid" do? You either specify the types or you don't, no?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Check the answer below, where you need to specify size and alignment and obtain some benefits regardless (no heap allocs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic `some`.

The `T` copy/assign/move/etc can be implemented in terms of `emplace`.  SFINAE using `can_store<T>` can ensure that only types the `some` can actually store are assignable to it, avoiding needless exceptions.

Currently, moving from `some` destroys its contents instead of just moving from it.  And a `some` can be empty (they are "nulllable").

`load_from` is a 'can-fail' copy constructor from another `some` -- it returns `false` on failure.  I could add a 'cannot-fail' from a smaller `some` (even a copy/assignment operator) to complete it.

`some_meta` is a manual virtual function table.  One exists per type `T` you store in a `some` of any size.  It stores the type-erased operations on the type `T` that `some` wants to use (in this case, copy move and destroy), plus some data about the type (size, alignment and type identity).  It could be augmented with additional operations like comparison and serialization.  For binary operations, logic to handle "no matching type" has to be considered.  For stuff like serialization, I'd have it call the free function `serialize` and `deserialize` on the `T`.  In both cases, we impose additional requirements on what `some` can store (you can, with a bit of work, handle "maybe serialize", but that gets messy).

You could even imagine a system where you can store a set of operations to perform on the data (binary and unary) and pass said operations bundled in types passed to some.  At this point, we are approaching `boost`'s type erasure library, however.

```
namespace details {
template<std::size_t Size, std::size_t Align=0>
struct storage_helper {
  using type = std::aligned_storage_t<Size, Align>;
  enum { alignment = alignof(type), size = Size };
};
template<std::size_t Size>
struct storage_helper<Size, 0> {
  using type = std::aligned_storage_t<Size>;
  enum { alignment = alignof(type), size = Size };
};
template<std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
using storage_helper_t = typename storage_helper<size,align>::type;

template<class T>using type=T;
struct some_meta {
  type<void(void*)>* destroy;
  type<void(void* dest, void const* src)>* copy;
  type<void(void* dest, void* src)>* move;
  std::type_index type;
  size_t size;
  size_t align;
  template<class T> static some_meta const* get() {
    static const some_meta retval( create<T>() );
    return &retval;
  };
  private:
  template<class T> static some_meta create() {
    return {
        [](void* p){ ((T*)p)->~T(); },
        [](void* out, void const* in){ new(out)T(*(T*)in); },
        [](void* dest, void* src) { new(dest)T(std::move(*(T*)src)); },
        typeid(T),
        sizeof(T),
        alignof(T)
    };
  }
};
}

template<class>struct emplace_as{};

template< std::size_t size, std::size_t Align=0 >
struct some {
  enum { align = details::storage_helper<size, Align>::alignment };
  using data_type = details::storage_helper_t<size, Align>;

  template<size_t, size_t> friend struct some;
  template<class T> struct can_store :
    std::integral_constant< bool, ((align%alignof(T))==0) && sizeof(T) <= size) >
  {};

  template<size_t x, size_t a>
  static bool can_fit( some<x,a> const& o ) {
    if (x<=size && ((align%some<x,a>::align)==0)) return true; // should cause optimizations
    if (!o.meta) return true;
    if (o.meta->size > size) return false;
    if (o.meta->align > align) return false;
    return true;
  }
private:
  data_type data;
  details::some_meta const* meta = nullptr;
public:
  // true iif we are (exactly) a T
  template<class T>
  bool is() const {
      return meta && (meta->type == typeid(T));
  }

  explicit operator bool()const { return meta!=nullptr; }

  template<class T>
  T* unsafe_get() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data); }

  template<class T>
  T* get() { if (is<T>()) return unsafe_get<T>(); else return nullptr; }

  void clear() { if (meta) meta->destroy(&data); meta = nullptr; }

  template<class T, class... Args>
  std::enable_if_t< can_store<T>{} >
  emplace(Args&&...args) {
    clear();

    new(&data) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    meta = details::some_meta::get<T>();
  }
  some()=default;
  some(some const& o) {
    *this = o;
  }
  some(some const&&o):some(o){}
  some(some&o):some(const_cast<some const&>(o)){}
  some(some&& o) {
    *this = std::move(o);
  }

  some& operator=(some const&o) {
    if (this == &o) return *this;
    clear();
    if (o.meta) {
      o.meta->copy( &data, &o.data );
      meta=o.meta;
    }
    return *this;
  }        
  some& operator=(some &&o) {
    if (this == &o) return *this;
    clear();
    if (o.meta) {
      o.meta->move( &data, &o.data );
      meta=o.meta;
      o.clear();
    }
    return *this;
  }
  some& operator=(some const&&o) { return *this=o; }
  some& operator=(some &o) { return *this=const_cast<some const&>(o); }

  // from non-some:
  template<class T,class=std::enable_if_t<can_store<std::decay_t<T>>{}>>
  some(T&& t){
    emplace<std::decay_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
  template<class T, class...Args,class=std::enable_if_t<can_store<T>{}>>
  some( emplace_as<T>, Args&&...args ){
    emplace<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  template<class T,class=std::enable_if_t<can_store<std::decay_t<T>>{}>>
  some& operator=(T&&t){
    emplace<std::decay_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(t));
    return *this;
  }

  template<size_t x, size_t a>
  bool load_from( some<x,a> const& o ) {
    if ((void*)&o==this) return true;
    if (!can_fit(o)) return false;
    clear();
    if (o.meta) {
      o.meta->copy( &data, &o.data );
      meta=o.meta;
    }
    return true;
  }
  template<size_t x, size_t a>
  bool load_from( some<x,a> && o ) {
    if ((void*)&o==this) return true;
    if (!can_fit(o)) return false;
    clear();
    if (o.meta) {
      o.meta->move( &data, &o.data );
      meta=o.meta;
      o.clear();
    }
    return true;
  }
  ~some() { clear(); }
};

template<class T, class...Ts>
using some_that_fits = some< (std::max)({sizeof(T),sizeof(Ts)...}), (std::max)({alignof(T),alignof(Ts)...}) >;
```

the `meta` object is a manually implemented virtual function table, basically.  It reduces the memory overhead of a given `some` to one pointer (above its storage buffer).

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7abd8fea382113c0)

As demonstrated above, it is quite viable.

Note that `create` returns a pointer to the same `meta` for the same type `T`, even if called more than once.

I have exercised about half the code paths in my test above.  The others probably have bugs.

`some_that_fits` lets you pass a set of types, and it returns a `some` type that fits those types.

No exceptions, other than those generated by the operations on the stored types by said stored types, are thrown.  When possible, I test at compile time to ensure types fit.

I could possibly add support for greater alignment, small storage types by starting them at an offset into my data?

Comment: This is the `variant` path towards the hybrid. There is also the other path, starting with `any`, reflecting the 2 ways type erasure may be done in `C++`.

Comment: @user1095108 in what way?  Failing early is obvious, exception-based extension is easy (I just didn't bother doing it).  Admittdly I don't have the `.type()` method that `any()` has, but that is also trivial.  I am also missing `swap`, but that is in both interfaces.  Is it just `.get<T>` instead of `any_cast<T>` that you are talking about?  That seems superficial to me.  Is there something else?

Comment: Your class template is good, I wasn't criticizing. There are 2 ways to do type erasure: one is via function pointers, as you did, the other via virtual functions - as `any` does it. Your class is more `variant`-like than `any`-like, that's all I wanted to say. BUT, there are things that a `variant` can do, which are impossible here, for example, comparison operators and supporting streams is cumbersome.

Comment: @user1095108 `virtual` is merely an implementation detail.  `any` could switch to function pointers without changing its interface or behavior in the slightest.  But by not using `virtual`, I avoid having to specify the types supported (ie, I can make my `some` parametrized on the size and alignment requirements of the stored types, instead of the size and alignment requirements of the implementation detail wrapping class for the stored types).  Adding additional operations to type erase -- comparison and streams -- is not that hard (types stored must support any such type erased operation).

Comment: For comparisons you would store additional function pointers?

Comment: @user1095108 yes, in the `meta_some`.  And naturally they would only work between identical types, so you'd check that first.  A rule describing what to do when they are not identical needs to invented (`type_index` is ordered, so we can use that ordering).  Note that this restricts the set of types you can store in the `some`, as objects without `<` no longer qualify.  For serialize, the same rule applies -- any type stored must have an ADL-findable `serialize( archive, t )` and `deserialize( archive, t )` free functions, and you augment the `meta_some` and `some` interface.

Comment: BTW: `aligned_storage` guarantees, that it will provide maximum alignment for all objects of some size. I suspect you can drop the alignment parameter and the alignment checks.

Comment: @user1095108 defaulting align to zero gives maximal alignment to the size support added.