# Polymorphism in C++ STL containers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, polymorphism

I was wondering if an elegant solution exists to this problem.

Suppose the following:

```
class Base {
  private:
    int data;
  protected:
    Base(int data) : data(data) { }
    int getData() const { return data; }
    virtual bool someOp() = 0;
}

class Derived1 : public Base {
  private:
    int data2;
  public:
    Derived1(int data, int data2) : Base(data), data2(data2) { }
    int getData2() const { return data2; }
    bool someOp() override { /* something */ }
}

class Derived2 : public Base {
  private:
    float data2;
  public:
    Derived1(int data, float data2) : Base(data), data2(data2) { }
    float getData2() const { return data2; }
    bool someOp() override { /* something */ }
}
```

And suppose that I have the total control over the hierarchy so I can assume that `Base` won't get extended, nor any `DerivedX` class.

Now I want to store them in a `std::vector`, if I want to use polymorphism I'm forced to store pointers otherwise object slicing will prevent me to store the additional derived properties. So I'm basically forced to use a `std::vector<unique_ptr<Base>>`.

But let's assume that I need to store plenty of these objects and I don't want to waste for double heap allocation (the internal `std::vector` + the object itself) and that at the same time I can assume that:

- the class hierarchy is perfectly defined and won't be extended without knowing it
- `sizeof(DerivedX)` won't be so larger than `sizeof(Base)`

So I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to keep polymorphism and avoid storing pointers. I could think of some solutions like

```
class Base {
  enum {
   DERIVED1,
   DERIVED2
  } type;

  int data;
  union {
    int derived1data;
    float derived2data;
  }

  bool someOp() {
    if (this->type == DERIVED1) ...
    else if ..
  }
}
```

But this is clearly not elegant. I could also try to exploit the fact that object slicing shouldn't occur if `sizeof(Derived) == sizeof(Base)` by using a protected union in `Base` and accessing it from `Derived` and casting the address to elements in the `std::vector` to the desired type (according to an enum) but this sounds ugly too.

Comment: You might want to take a look at boost::variant...

Comment: Yes, `boost::variant`, along with its associated `apply_visitor` is what came to mind for me.  You would need to know all the derived types in advance, though.

Comment: The relationship between Base and DerivedX is irrelevant when using boost_variant. Might just as well be N unrelated classes.

Comment: If you can guarantee they will be the same size (which might depend on your compiler) You can just check the type in a switch and then cast with static_cast. You can use static_assert to make sure they're the same size at compile time.

Comment: Knowing derived classes beforehand, a struct holding a type identifier + the union of the base + derived types is a valid approach. However, not all data types are applicable for a union (C++11 allows more) and maintain/extend the hierarchy might be problematic. (Note: You might split the class from it's data structure: class X { private: Data data; }

Comment: boost pointer container library have value semantics during item retrieval, perhaps with a block allocator http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Comment: I upvoted the suggestions to use boost::variant<>; As @n.m. pointed out, this is a bit more general; You could use the same technique as variant to store the objects (allocate enough raw bytes to hold on the largest Derived object, use placement new), and deviate from variant only in that you could actually use RTTI to figure out which type you're actually storing - so, you'll save on the int inside variant<> that remembers what exact type is stored. So really, ape boost::variant, but use dynamic casts or type_info to implement the equivalent of the varaint::which() method to save space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type erasure and the small buffer optimization.

You can type erase almost any property in C++, creating a custom interface that "knows" how to apply the property to a now-unknown type.

`boost::any` type erases down to copy, destroy, get typeid, and cast-back-to-exactly-matching-type.  `std::function` type erases down to copy, invoke with a specific signature, destroy, and cast-back-to-identical-type (the last is rarely used).

Free store based type erasure implementations get move semantics 'for free' by swapping around pointers.

In your case, you'll want to create a "large enough" aligned storage in the type.  You'll want to type erase down to copy, get-as-reference-to-base, destroy and probably move (as you are storing internally).

`std::aligned_storage` is intended for your task (you can pass in the alignment requirements of all the types you intend to store).  Then in-place new the object.

Build a table of the operations you want to perform on the object via `void*` -- copy, move, destroy, and convert-to-`base*`.

```
template<class Sig>using f = Sig*;

struct table {
  f<base*(void*)>             convert_to_base;
  f<base const*(void const*)> convert_to_const_base;
  f<void(void*,void const*)>  copy_construct;
  f<void(void*)>              destroy;
  f<void(void*,void*)>        move_construct;
};
template<class T>
table const* get_table() {
  static table t = {
    // convert to base:
    [](void*p)->base*{
      T*t=static_cast<T*>(p);
      return t;
    },
    // convert to const base:
    [](void const*p)->base const*{
      T const*t=static_cast<T const*>(p);
      return t;
    },
    // etc
  };
  return &t;
}
```

now store `get_table<T>()` in your type-erased instance (it is basically a virtual function table, manually implemented), and write your wrapping regular class to use the functions from the `table` to manipulate the `aligned_storage<?...>`.

Now, this can be done easier by using `boost::variant`, or via something like my [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27173377/1774667) type that acts like a `any` without using heap storage.  The some link includes an implementation that compiles of the pseudo-virtual function table technique above.  I probably used aligned storage wrong, however, so be careful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use std::aligned_storage to wrap your classes. Assuming that Derived2 is the largest:

```
class Storage
{
public:
  Storage(int data, int data2)
  {
    new (&data) Derived1(data, data2);
  }
  Storage(int data, float data2)
  {
    new (&data) Derived2(data, data2);
  }
  Base* getBase()
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<Base*>(&data);
  }
  ~Storage()
  {
    getBase()->Base::~Base();
  }
private:
  std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Derived2)> data;
};
```

Comment: Casting a pointer to buffer created as a `Derived1` to `Base*` is undefined behavior in the general case.  There are even subtle practical cases where it breaks down.  If you want to convert to `Base*` safely, first reinterpret cast to the correct `DerivedX*`, then implicit or static cast to `Base*`.

Comment: @Yakk, sure, I didn't intent to give the universal solution, just an easy-to-understand draft for the particular task. Your approach is more fundamental.